# Delete character/insert character in a string

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I need to delete or replace the third ":" (colon) with a space. I can't do it at a certain index because the entries differ in length.

```
u:Testuser:rw:/home/user1/temp
g:Testgroup:-:/home/user2/temp
```

Result should look like this:

```
u:Testuser:rw /home/user1/temp
g:Testgroup:- /home/user2/temp
```

Is there a way to 1) delete a specific character and 2) to insert a character before/after a specific character?
I couldn´t find a solution, I am a beginner unfortunately.

Comment: This could easily be done with [bash string manipulation](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/). Or through awk. Or even sed.

Comment: I dont know how to tell the script to delete/insert at the third colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, I did it myself

```
g:Testgroup:-:/home/user2/temp | sed s/':'/' '/3
```

Answer (score 0):

A dirty solution:

```
$ cat 54042857.txt
u:Testuser:rw:/home/user1/temp
g:Testgroup:-:/home/user2/temp

$ awk -F ':' ' { print $1":"$2":"$3" "$4 } ' 54042857.txt 
u:Testuser:rw /home/user1/temp
g:Testgroup:- /home/user2/temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ foo='u:Testuser:rw:/home/user1/temp'
$ printf '%s\n' "${foo%":${foo#*:*:*:}"} ${foo#*:*:*:}"
u:Testuser:rw /home/user1/temp
```